# Producing two outputs from a Linker script

Tags: makefile, ld, stm32f7

There is a Quad-SPI NOR device on the STM32F746G-Discovery Board that I would like to use to store read only data.

So the ideal would be that the linker file produces an ELF file for the F746G flash and a hex file to program the NOR.

Then I could use the STM32 ST-LINK Utility to program the target and the External Loader to program the NOR.

Can anyone kindly point me to how this might be done?

Answer (score 0):

How about you invoke the linker two times, one time for the ELF output and the other time for the HEX output and for each invocation feeding in only those compilation units / object files that shall go into the respective binary.

Comment: Then `objcopy`ing the HEX ELF (because no linker outputs raw binary) to get the NOR image.